# Seleccionar y dar formato a un texto de un Text de Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Dentro de un widget Text de Tkinter, en Python, cargo un documento.
Tras analizar el contenido y localizar ciertas palabras del mismo, debo seleccionarlas para darles un determinado formato, concretamente, darles un color de fondo y ponerlas en negrita. Por ejemplo, si tengo este contenido, debería seleccionar las palabras que ya pongo en cursiva (y darle un color de fondo y ponerlas en negrita):

Esto es un texto *cualquiera* dónde tengo que *seleccionar* ciertas *palabras* y darles *algún* tipo de formato.

Entonces, ¿me podría decir alguien, con un ejemplo, como se selecciona un determinado cacho o cachos (palabra o palabras) del contenido de un Text para, luego, darles el mencionado formato? Supongo que se podrán seleccionar más de una palabra en diferentes lugares separados del mismo contenido.
He visto algo de la documentación pero no he entendido cómo se hace.

Entorno de trabajo: Python2.7.x - Ubuntu 16.04

---

**Editado**

Yo tengo en la ventana principal dos widgets Text de Tkinter:

- En el primer elemento Text, llamado, por ejemplo `txt_ini`, cargo el texto de un documento, por ejemplo, el que ya he puesto antes dos veces para tener más repeticiones y, además, considerar los cambios o saltos de línea:

> Esto es un texto cualquiera dónde tengo que seleccionar ciertas palabras y darles algún tipo de formato.
>
> Esto es un texto cualquiera dónde tengo que seleccionar ciertas palabras y darles algún tipo de formato.

Tengo que localizar ciertas palabras en ese contenido cargado. Las palabras a buscar son las claves del siguiente diccionario. Y que serán sustituidas por otras palabras que son los valores del mismo diccionario. Este es el diccionario en cuestión:

```
dicc_palabras = {
    1: ['cualquiera', 'al azar'],
    2: ['seleccionar', 'elegir'],
    3: ['palabras', 'partes'],
    4: ['algún', 'este']
}
```

Bueno, una vez procesado el contenido y localizadas ciertas palabras a buscar, se cargará el mismo contenido pero, ahora, con esas palabras localizadas a las que se les habrá aplicado un determinado formato de estilo (en este editor, solo **negrita** pero podría ser cambiar el color de fondo u otras opciones). Algo parecido a esto:

> Esto es un texto **cualquiera** dónde tengo que **seleccionar** ciertas **palabras** y darles **algún** tipo de formato.
>
> Esto es un texto **cualquiera** dónde tengo que **seleccionar** ciertas **palabras** y darles **algún** tipo de formato.

- En el segundo Text, llamado, por ejemplo, `txt_fin`, aparecerá el contenido con las palabras sustituidas. Palabras sustitutas a las que se les habrá aplicado otro formato de estilo:

> Esto es un texto **al azar** dónde tengo que **elegir** ciertas **partes** y darles **este** tipo de formato.
>
> Esto es un texto **al azar** dónde tengo que **elegir** ciertas **partes** y darles **este** tipo de formato.

Todo este proceso para que se vea más clara la comparativa del texto antes y después de procesarlo, para ver el contenido original resaltando las **palabras localizadas** y el contenido ya procesado resaltando, también, las **palabras sustitutas**.

Comment: ¿Con "seleccionar" te refieres a hacerlo manualmente como comúnmente se hace con el ratón en cualquier editor o que busque y formatee ciertas palabras automáticamente (en base a una expresión regular, una lista de palabras, etc)?

Comment: Me refiero a que en un momento dado dentro del texto aparecerán ciertas palabras sobresaltadas con un fondo de diferente color y en negrita, por ejemplo. Voy a editar la pregunta a ver si queda algo más claro. Igual, la opción que vi en la documentación (que no llegue a comprender bien), con el insert() y lo de añadir etiquetas (add_tag) se refiera a hacer selecciones manualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, ya tengo el resultado que quería. Al menos, en esta prueba me va bien. Veremos luego cuando lo pase al prototipo final.

Empezando con el código, directamente.

```
# encoding: utf-8


# Solución de importación para que las palabras con tildes
# u otros caracteres raros sean bien consideradas como en Python 3.x
#from __future__ import unicode_literals
# Se opta por usar el decode('utf-8') cuando haga falta (ver más abajo)


from Tkinter import *

import os


class MiTkinter(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        frame_btn = Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame_btn.pack(fill='both')
        frame_btn.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.btn_toggle_01 = Button(frame_btn, text='Cambio a BLANCO', command=self.toggle_accion)
        self.btn_toggle_01.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        #self.btn_toggle_01.config(padx=6, pady=4)

        self.btn_toggle_02 = Button(frame_btn, text='Fondo en NEGRO', relief='sunken', command=self.toggle_accion)
        self.btn_toggle_02.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        #self.btn_toggle_02.config(padx=6, pady=4)

        frame_txt = Frame(self, bg='grey')
        frame_txt.pack()
        frame_txt.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        # Valor(es) Predeterminado(s)
        self.bg_color = 'black'
        self.fg_color = 'white'

        self.txt_ini = Text(frame_txt, wrap=WORD, bd=0)
        self.txt_ini.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.txt_ini.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=('Consolas', 12), selectbackground='lightblue', width=22, height=16, bg=self.bg_color, fg=self.fg_color, insertbackground=self.fg_color, highlightbackground=self.bg_color, highlightcolor=self.fg_color)

        self.txt_fin = Text(frame_txt, wrap=WORD, bd=0)
        self.txt_fin.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, pady=15, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.txt_fin.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=('Consolas', 12), selectbackground='lightblue', width=22, height=16, bg=self.bg_color, fg=self.fg_color, insertbackground=self.fg_color, highlightbackground=self.bg_color, highlightcolor=self.fg_color)

        dicc_palabras = {
            1: ['cualquiera', 'al azar'],
            2: ['seleccionar', 'elegir'],
            3: ['palabras', 'partes'],
            4: ['algún', 'este']
        }

        txt_ini_contenido = '''Esto es un texto cualquiera dónde tengo que seleccionar ciertas palabras y darles algún tipo de formato.

Esto es un texto cualquiera dónde tengo que seleccionar ciertas palabras y darles algún tipo de formato.'''
        txt_fin_contenido = '''Esto es un texto al azar dónde tengo que elegir ciertas partes y darles este tipo de formato.

Esto es un texto al azar dónde tengo que elegir ciertas partes y darles este tipo de formato.'''

        self.txt_ini.insert(1.0, txt_ini_contenido)
        self.txt_fin.insert(1.0, txt_fin_contenido)

        # Número de líneas del contenido de un determinado Text
        txt_ini_num_lin = int(self.txt_ini.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])
        txt_fin_num_lin = int(self.txt_fin.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])

        self.resaltar_palabra(self.txt_ini, txt_ini_num_lin, dicc_palabras)
        self.resaltar_palabra(self.txt_fin, txt_fin_num_lin, dicc_palabras)


    def resaltar_palabra(self, _Text, _num_lin, _dicc_palabras):

        if(_Text == self.txt_ini):
            #print('Formateando el "txt_ini"...')
            _dicc_i = 0
            bg_color = 'red'

        elif(_Text == self.txt_fin):
            #print('Formateando el "txt_fin"...')
            _dicc_i = 1
            bg_color = 'green'

        for lin in range(1, _num_lin+1):
            lin_str = '{}.0'.format(lin)

            for _k_ in _dicc_palabras:
                palabra = _dicc_palabras[_k_][_dicc_i]
                # Al querer calcular la longitud de cada palabra, se observa
                # que, al menos, por cada carácter con tilde, se suma 1
                # a la longitud final de la palabra, como, por ejemplo,
                # en el caso de "algún".
                # haciendo un simple len('algún'), en vez de 5, sale 6.
                # Pero si, primero, se pasa la palabra a unicode el
                # resultado sale correcto, osea,
                #     len('algún'.decode('utf-8')) >> 5  
                # Otra opción, en vez del decode() es descomentar
                # el import referido al "unicode_literals"
                palabra_len = len(palabra.decode('utf-8'))

                # search()
                # Recogiendo la posición en la que se sitúa la palabra
                # en el contenido.
                #   -> se busca una cadena (o una expresión regular)
                #   desde la posición '1.0' (línea 1, carácter 0).
                #   -> el índice devuelto es del estilo X.Y
                #       >> X, el número de línea contando desde 1.
                #       >> Y, el número de carácter contando desde 0.
                plbra_i_ini = _Text.search(palabra, lin_str)
                # Índice de la línea en la que está situada la palabra
                plbra_i_linea = plbra_i_ini.split('.')[0]
                plbra_i_ini = plbra_i_ini.split('.')[1]
                # Calculando el índice final tras el fin de la palabra
                plbra_i_fin = int(plbra_i_ini) + palabra_len
                # construyendo índices válidos para el tag_add
                plbra_i_ini = '{}.{}'.format(plbra_i_linea, plbra_i_ini)
                plbra_i_fin = '{}.{}'.format(plbra_i_linea, plbra_i_fin)

                # Configurando y añadiendo la TAG en el lugar adecuado, según
                # los índices configurados, para formatear la palabra deseada
                _Text.tag_configure('highlightline', background=bg_color, font='helvetica 11 bold')
                _Text.tag_add('highlightline', plbra_i_ini, plbra_i_fin)


    '''
    Otra función EXTRA de regalo para el que le interese:
    Cambio de estilo en los Text según se pulse un botón u otro
    '''
    def toggle_accion(self):

        if self.btn_toggle_01.config('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
            self.btn_toggle_01.config(relief='raised', text='Cambio a BLANCO')
        else:
            self.btn_toggle_01.config(relief='sunken', text='Fondo en BLANCO')

        if self.btn_toggle_02.config('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
            self.btn_toggle_02.config(relief='raised', text='Cambio a NEGRO')
        else:
            self.btn_toggle_02.config(relief='sunken', text='Fondo en NEGRO')

        if self.btn_toggle_01.config('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
            self.bg_color = 'white'
            self.fg_color = 'black'
        else:
            self.bg_color = 'black'
            self.fg_color = 'white'

        self.txt_ini.config(bg=self.bg_color, fg=self.fg_color, insertbackground=self.fg_color, highlightbackground=self.bg_color, highlightcolor=self.fg_color)
        self.txt_fin.config(bg=self.bg_color, fg=self.fg_color, insertbackground=self.fg_color, highlightbackground=self.bg_color, highlightcolor=self.fg_color)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Limpia consola antes de empezar ejecución
    os.system('clear')

    # Tk (Raíz) objeto raíz por defecto
    # ==========================================================
    root = MiTkinter()

    root.title('Probando ~ Acción Toggle con Botones y Selección de Palabras')
    root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(548, 412, 400, 100))

    root.mainloop()
```

Aquí una imagen de cómo me queda el resultado final de la prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues eso, ahí va para toda persona a la que le pueda servir.
También, los expertos a ver qué dicen de la solución, si quieren aportar mejoras.

Bueno, al final buscando algo más por Internet o revisando algo más documentación al respecto he llegado a conseguir el resultado expuesto. También, toda colaboración o ayuda ha sido buena para encontrar el resultado deseado.

Algunos enlaces al respecto:

- http://www6.uniovi.es/tcl/tutorial/cap17.html
- http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html

Y, de paso, un EXTRA sobre acciones de botón, una especie de Toggle.

Saludos.

---

**Editado**

Bueno, al final, como ya se leyó en uno de los comentarios de esta respuesta, el código expuesto en la parte de arriba de ésta misma no considera la repetición de la palabra buscada si se encuentra en la misma línea.

Así que, basándome en la otra solución sugerida, tras tratar de comprenderla y navegando un poco más por la extensa Internet, he añadido un apaño que, ahora sí, considera las mencionadas repeticiones.

Entre otras cosas, he dejado el `for` que recorría cada línea del contenido del Text a tratar porque, al final, no es algo útil para el objetivo a conseguir.

He añadido algo más de contenido con más palabras repetidas a cada uno de los Text.

Pues este es el código:

```
# encoding: utf-8


# Solución de importación para que las palabras con tildes
# u otros caracteres raros sean bien consideradas como en Python 3.x
#from __future__ import unicode_literals
# Se opta por usar el decode('utf-8') cuando haga falta (ver más abajo)


from Tkinter import *

import os


class MiTkinter(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        frame_btn = Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame_btn.pack(fill='both')
        frame_btn.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.btn_toggle_01 = Button(frame_btn, text='Cambio a BLANCO', command=self.toggle_accion)
        self.btn_toggle_01.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)

        self.btn_toggle_02 = Button(frame_btn, text='Fondo en NEGRO', relief='sunken', command=self.toggle_accion)
        self.btn_toggle_02.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

        frame_txt = Frame(self, bg='grey')
        frame_txt.pack()
        frame_txt.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        # Valor(es) Predeterminado(s)
        self.bg_color = 'black'
        self.fg_color = 'white'

        self.txt_ini = Text(frame_txt, wrap=WORD, bd=0)
        self.txt_ini.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.txt_ini.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=('Consolas', 11), selectbackground='lightblue', width=24, height=16, bg=self.bg_color, fg=self.fg_color, insertbackground=self.fg_color, highlightbackground=self.bg_color, highlightcolor=self.fg_color)

        self.txt_fin = Text(frame_txt, wrap=WORD, bd=0)
        self.txt_fin.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.txt_fin.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=('Consolas', 11), selectbackground='lightblue', width=24, height=16, bg=self.bg_color, fg=self.fg_color, insertbackground=self.fg_color, highlightbackground=self.bg_color, highlightcolor=self.fg_color)

        dicc_palabras = {
            1: ['cualquiera', 'al azar'],
            2: ['seleccionar', 'elegir'],
            3: ['palabras', 'partes'],
            4: ['algún', 'cierto']
        }

        txt_ini_contenido = '''Esto es un texto cualquiera, bien digo cualquiera, dónde tengo que seleccionar diversas palabras y darles algún tipo de formato. Algún tipo de resultado es el que da. Esperando que "álgún" resultado, sea el mejor.

De algún modo, en cierto lugar del texto cualquiera, voy a seleccionar varias palabras y darles algún tipo de formato. Deseando que las palabras a seleccionar sean las adecuadas.'''
        txt_fin_contenido = '''Esto es un texto al azar, bien digo al azar, dónde tengo que elegir diversas partes y darles cierto tipo de formato. Cierto tipo de resultado es el que da. Esperando que "ciérto" resultado sea el mejor.

De cierto modo, en algún lugar del texto al azar, voy a elegir varias partes y darles este tipo de formato. Deseando que las partes a elegir sean las adecuadas.'''
        self.txt_ini.insert(1.0, txt_ini_contenido)
        self.txt_fin.insert(1.0, txt_fin_contenido)

        self.resaltar_palabra(self.txt_ini, dicc_palabras)
        self.resaltar_palabra(self.txt_fin, dicc_palabras)


    def resaltar_palabra(self, _Text, _dicc_palabras):

        if(_Text == self.txt_ini):
            print('\nFormateando el "txt_ini"...')
            print('=================================================')
            _dicc_i = 0
            bg_color = 'red'
            tag_nom = 'orig'

        elif(_Text == self.txt_fin):
            print('\nFormateando el "txt_fin"...')
            print('=================================================')
            _dicc_i = 1
            bg_color = 'green'
            tag_nom = 'anon'

        for _k_ in _dicc_palabras:
            palabra = _dicc_palabras[_k_][_dicc_i]
            # Al querer calcular la longitud de cada palabra, se observa
            # que, al menos, por cada carácter con tilde, se suma 1
            # a la longitud final de la palabra, como, por ejemplo,
            # en el caso de "algún".
            # haciendo un simple len('algún'), en vez de 5, sale 6.
            # Pero si, primero, se pasa la palabra a unicode el
            # resultado sale correcto, osea,
            #     len('algún'.decode('utf-8')) >> 5  
            # Otra opción, en vez del decode() es descomentar
            # el import referido al "unicode_literals"
            palabra_len = len(palabra.decode('utf-8'))

            # search()
            # Recogiendo la posición en la que se sitúa la palabra
            #   -> se busca una cadena (o una expresión regular)
            #   desde la posición '1.0' (línea 1, carácter 0).
            #   -> el índice devuelto es del estilo X.Y
            #       >> X, el número de línea contando desde 1.
            #       >> Y, el número de carácter contando desde 0.

            '''
            Podría darse el caso de haber más de una repetición de palabra
            en la misma línea analizada:
                Por eso:
                    -> Hay que considerar las posibles repeticiones de la palabra en la misma línea recorrida.
            '''

            index = '1.0'
            while True:
                plbra_i = _Text.search(palabra, index, stopindex=END)
                if not plbra_i:
                    break
                plbra_i_ini = int(plbra_i.split('.')[0])
                plbra_i_fin  = int(plbra_i.split('.')[1]) + palabra_len
                coords = '{}.{}'.format(plbra_i_ini, plbra_i_fin)
                _Text.tag_add(tag_nom, plbra_i, coords)
                _Text.tag_configure(tag_nom, background=bg_color, font='helvetica 11 bold')
                index = coords


    def toggle_accion(self):

        if self.btn_toggle_01.config('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
            self.btn_toggle_01.config(relief='raised', text='Cambio a BLANCO')
        else:
            self.btn_toggle_01.config(relief='sunken', text='Fondo en BLANCO')

        if self.btn_toggle_02.config('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
            self.btn_toggle_02.config(relief='raised', text='Cambio a NEGRO')
        else:
            self.btn_toggle_02.config(relief='sunken', text='Fondo en NEGRO')

        if self.btn_toggle_01.config('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
            self.bg_color = 'white'
            self.fg_color = 'black'
        else:
            self.bg_color = 'black'
            self.fg_color = 'white'

        self.txt_ini.config(bg=self.bg_color, fg=self.fg_color, insertbackground=self.fg_color, highlightbackground=self.bg_color, highlightcolor=self.fg_color)
        self.txt_fin.config(bg=self.bg_color, fg=self.fg_color, insertbackground=self.fg_color, highlightbackground=self.bg_color, highlightcolor=self.fg_color)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Limpia consola antes de empezar ejecución
    os.system('clear')

    # Tk (Raíz) objeto raíz por defecto
    # ==========================================================
    root = MiTkinter()

    root.title('Probando ~ Acción Toggle con Botones y Selección de Palabras')
    root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(568, 402, 400, 100))

    root.mainloop()
```

Y el resultado en imagen de muestra es éste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve, toda repetición de palabra es considerada tanto en la misma línea, como en otras líneas antes o después. Claro que, como se ve, también, lo que se considera es la palabra exacta, es decir, que si se busca la palabra **algún**, se buscará, exactamente, la palabra escrita de esa forma. Si sale la palabra en mayúsculas, sin tilde, ..., no será considerada. Para eso, habría que considerar más parámetros y, supongo, que para esos casos, será mejor emplear una Expresión Regular (Regex).

Pues eso, para todo el que le pueda servir. Gracias por las colaboraciones.

Comment: Por ahorrarme código e ir al grano, he cargado los dos Text con un contenido inicial y he explicado más que nada como llegar al objetivo final de resaltar las palabras adecuadas. Luego, en verdad, si sería cargar contenido en el primer Text, analizar el contenido, localizar las palabras, formatear el texto, según el caso, para uno u otro Text y mostrar el resultado final como la imagen.

Comment: Gracias por compartir el código zacktagnan. En tu caso dejas el procesado del texto enteramente a Python lo cual dependiendo del caso puede ser una buena opción. Solo una observación,  con esta aproximación  solo buscas una coincidencia por palabra objetivo en una misma línea  (si una palabra objetivo se repite en la misma línea solo la primera es encontrada y substituida). Además no discrimina palabras como tales, sino subcadenas, es decir si buscas "rama" la palabra "prog**rama**ción" es una diana al contener la subcadena "rama".

Comment: Esto no significa que sea un error, si es esto lo que buscas tu  aproximación es buena. Por cierto me apunto el tutorial sobre Tcl-Tk de la U. de Oviedo, no lo conocía, aunque sea algo antiguo dado que no abunda la documentación en español siempre se agradece. Un saludo.

Comment: ¡Vaya! Me has pillado con el carrito del helado. :) Pues, es verdad, ni me había dado cuenta de eso que dices si hay más de una repetición en la misma línea. Puede que eso me afecte cuando lo pase al aplicativo final. Tendré que ver cómo corregir eso para tenerlo en cuenta. ¿Tu solución si lo contempla? ... En cuanto a que la palabra esté contenida en otra, eso si que no lo tendría que considerar ... Me alegro que la documentación extra te satisfaga ... Y, si, se hecha de menos documentación en castellano. Que le vamos a hacer. Saludos.

Comment: Otra cosa que no he probado ... Así, a modo de pregunta rápida, sin mirar nada, si si o si no ... ¿Se podría hacer lo mismo, tanto en tu solución, como en la mía, si, en vez de elementos Text se tratase de elementos Label? ¿En un Label, también, se puede emplear los TAGs y el INSERT para dar un formato al contenido del Label? ¿Conoces Gtk+3 que tiene varias formas de formatear el contenido de un Label, hasta con etiquetas HTML?

Comment: En cuanto a mi código, busca y sustituye todas las palabras que se encuentren en el texto estén repetidas las veces que estén y solo busca lo que se entiende como "palabra" en el el lenguaje cotidiano, es decir si el diccionario contiene `programa`  nunca será tenida en cuenta `programación` o `reprogramar`, pero si `programa.`, `programa;`, `¿programa?`, etc. Por eso lo de usar expresiones regulares. Se puede hacer que no diferencie entre mayúsculas y minúsculas mediante `nocase=True`, pero a la hora de sustituir habría que cambiar cosas para que se conserven las mayúsculas dónde estaban.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77867/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-zacktagnan).

Comment: No te cogí cuando proponías seguir por el chat. No obstante, te deje unos poquitos comentarios. Espero que los leas y me digas algo. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para sustituir una determinada parte del texto simplemente hay que usar los métodos `delete` e `insert` conjuntamente:

```
text_widget.delete(indice1, indice2)
text_widget.insert(indice1, "nuevo texto")
```

Para que una parte del texto presente un determinado formato se usan etiquetas, por ejemplo:

```
# Creamos una etiqueta
widget_text.tag_config('nombre_etiqueta',
                       background='#ff4d4d',
                       font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold")
                      )

# Aplicamos la etiqueta a un fragmento del texto usando indices de nuevo
widget_text.tag_add("nombre_etiqueta", indice_inicial, indice_final)
```

Con lo anterior tenemos la base, ahora solo queda saber como obtener los índices. Para buscar texto en un `Text` widget tenemos a nuestra disposición el método [`search`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.search-method).

Dado que pretendes buscar y substituir una lista de palabras, creo que la mejor opción es usar una expresión regular:

```
regex = "\y(?:Hola|StackOverflow)\y)"
```

La expresión anterior busca las **palabras** 'Hola' y 'StackOverflow'. Hay que tener en cuenta que hay diferencias entre la sintaxis de las [expresiones regulares en Tk-Tcl](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) y Python (módulo `re`), una de ellas afecta a al especificador para *word boundaries*, en Python y en la mayoría de motores modernos se usa `\b`/`\B` mientras que Tk-Tcl usa `\y`/`\Y`.

A la hora de buscar y substituir palabras es más simple recorrer el contenido desde el final hasta el principio y no al revés. La causa es que al sustituir podemos alterar los índices (al aumentar o reducir el número de caracteres del texto). Si lo hacemos desde atrás hacia delante no alteramos nunca los índices en el texto que queda por recorrer y no tendremos que hacer cálculos para ver la correspondencia entre los índices de ambos widgets `Text`.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
from tkFont import Font




class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text1 = tk.Text(self)
        self.text2 = tk.Text(self)
        self.search_and_replace_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Buscar y sustituir",
                                                command=self.search_and_replace
                                               )

        self.normal_font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=12)
        self.select_font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=12, weight="bold" )
        self.text1.configure(font=self.normal_font)
        self.text2.configure(font=self.normal_font)

        self.text1.tag_config('found', background='#ff4d4d', font=self.select_font)
        self.text2.tag_config('replaced', background='#d2ff4d', font=self.select_font)


        # Insertamos texto de ejemplo en el primer Text
        text = (u"Hola StackOverflow, tkinter es un binding de la biblioteca gráfica Tcl/Tk para Python.\n"
                u"Este ejemplo busca palabras en un array y las sustituye por otras."
                )
        print(text)
        self.text1.insert('1.0', text)

        self.text1.pack()
        self.text2.pack()
        self.search_and_replace_btn.pack()




    def search_and_replace(self):
        sustituciones = {u"tkinter":       u"Tkinter",
                         u"StackOverflow": u"StackOverflow en español",
                         u"biblioteca":    u"librería",
                         u"array":         u"lista",
                         u"sustituye":     u"cambia"}

        regex = r'\y(?:{})\y'.format('|'.join(sustituciones.keys()))

        self.text2.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        self.text2.insert('1.0', self.text1.get('1.0', tk.END))
        self.text1.tag_remove("failed", '1.0', tk.END)
        self.text2.tag_remove("passed", '1.0', tk.END)

        count = tk.IntVar(self)
        pos = self.text1.index("end")

        while True:
            pos = self.text1.search(regex,  pos, "1.0",  backwards=True, regexp=True, count=count)
            if not pos:
                break

            idx2  ='{}+{}c'.format(pos, count.get())

            self.text1.tag_add("found", pos, idx2)

            new = sustituciones[self.text1.get(pos, idx2)]
            self.text2.delete(pos, idx2)
            self.text2.insert(pos, new)
            self.text2.tag_add("replaced", pos, '{}+{}c'.format(pos, len(new)))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es solo un ejemplo simplificado, jugando con la expresión podemos modificar a nuestro gusto los criterios de búsqueda.

> **Nota:** Para hacer el código compatible con Python 3 basta con cambiar los imports por:
>
> ```
> import tkinter as tk    
> from tkinter.font import Font
> ```

Para más información sobre el funcionamiento de los índices, el cursor y las etiquetas puede ser de ayuda:

[Documentación de effbot sobre el widget Text (en inglés)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: ¡Vaya, ya estabas tardando! Jejejeje ... Justo me has pillado subiendo mi resultado. Había conseguido lo que quería. Luego, a la tarde lo terminaré de subir.

Comment: Probado este código de @FJSevilla. Buen código igualmente. Toda muy de manera profesional :) ... Gracias y saludos por tu inagotable colaboración.

Comment: Esto es tontería pero, trato de poner una mención a alguien, tal y como dice la ayuda de estos comentarios (con la @ seguido del nombre del usuario) pero mira que no acierto a que salga el dichoso enlace :) ... ¡Pues vaya!