# Label Tkinter varias lineas

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola buenas tengo un problema en mi aplicación al usar labels. El problema es que al escribir un texto largo, el texto continua y se sale de la ventana. Lo que quiero es que el texto no pase de la zona delimitada por la ventana, y se ponga como un párrafo en varias lineas en el espacio que hay disponible. Dejo un ejemplo que simula lo que estoy contando por si no me he explicado bien.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.geometry("400x500")
        self.text = tk.StringVar(value="Esto es un texto largo de ejemplo 
        para Stackoverflow. Esto es un texto largo de ejemplo para 
        Stackoverflow.")

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="text:").grid(column=0, row=0, 
        pady=10, padx=10, sticky="e")
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text=self.text.get()).grid(column=1, 
        row=0, pady=20, sticky="w")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkinter.Label` tiene un parámetro para definir cuando se debe romper un texto que supere cierto tamaño  en otra linea, que es `wraplength`.

```
self.label2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.text, wraplength=390)
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que **recibe la longitud a partir de la cual romper la cadena en pixeles, no en número de caracteres**. Esto es así para permitir que el código sea portable a cualquier plataforma y fuente, pero dificulta asignar un valor de forma dinámica cuando queremos que el texto se divida adecuadamente al redimensionar la ventana o el widget de forma automática. Para permitir esto lo que debemos hacer es modificar el parámetro una vez renderizado el widget, un ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.geometry("400x500")
        self.text = tk.StringVar(value=("Esto es un texto largo de ejemplo "
                                        "para Stackoverflow."
                                        "Esto es un texto largo de ejemplo "
                                        "para Stackoverflow."))

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="text:")
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="e")
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.text)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.label2.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=20, padx=10,  sticky="nswe")
        self.label2.bind( "<Configure>", self.on_label_resize)

    def on_label_resize(self,  event):
        event.widget["wraplength"] = event.width


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dos observaciones:

- Si asignas el texto al `Label` desde un `StringVar` usa el parámetro `textvariable` no `text`, esto hace que si se modifica la variable se modifique el `Label` automáticamente. Si quieres que esto no ocurra y que la asignación del texto sea estática  entonces si es correcto usar `text=string_var.get()`
- No uses `grid`, `pack` o `place` en la misma línea dónde instancias a no ser que no quieras una referencia al widget para usarla después, si haces

  ```
  self.label = tk.Label(self, text="text:").grid(...)
  ```

  El atributo `label` va a hacer referencia  a la salida del método `grid` (`None`), no a la instancia de `Label`, por lo que es inútil en un futuro para hacer referencia al widget.

Comment: Justo estaba viendo como utilizar el widget tk.Message() y es parecido al Label pero con varias lineas, aunque esto está bastante mejor la verdad. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Alfredo ya dependiendo de que quieras conseguir (si es para algo sencillo `Label` es lo más simple) también tienes `tkinter.Text` el cual permite modificar también como se debe dividir el texto en lineas (partiendo dejando palabras completas o partiendo la palabra final en dos), definir colores y otras propiedades para diferentes partes del texto usando etiquetas, etc. Aquí tienes dos preguntas sobre este widgets https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/167602/15089 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/166199/15089 que muestran algunas de sus posibilidades. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en TCL lo que usamos es que separamos como la mayoria de lenguajes separan los strings entre lineas\n con un retorno de carro o su caracter es "\n", aunque se pierde el efecto dinámico y se vuelve estatico.

y en python tambien funciona

```
self.text = tk.StringVar(value="Esto es un texto\nlargo de ejemplo\npara Stackoverflow.\nEsto es un texto largo\nde ejemplo para\nStackoverflow.")
```